# Gatling with gradle: Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gatling, scala-gatling

I try to setup gatling in my Spring Boot project, based on gradle, following this tutorial: http://brokenrhythm.blog/gradle-gatling-springboot-automation

Here is the tasks I wrote:

```
task runGatling(type: JavaExec) {
    description = 'Test load the Spring Boot web service with Gatling'
    group = 'Load Test'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs = [
            // workaround for https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2689
            "-Dgatling.core.directory.binaries=${sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs.toString()}",
            "-Dlogback.configurationFile=${logbackGatlingConfig()}"
    ]
    main = 'io.gatling.app.Gatling'
    args = [
            '--simulation', 'com.mypackage.loadtesting.Simulation',
            '--results-folder', "${buildDir}/gatling-results",
            '--binaries-folder', sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs.toString() // ignored because of above bug
    ]
}

def logbackGatlingConfig() {
    return sourceSets.test.resources.find { it.name == 'logback-gatling.xml' };
}
```

But when running `runGatling`, I reach the following error:

```
> Task :runGatling FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':runGatling' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Task ':runGatling' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
```

Comment: Why not use the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/lkishalmi/gradle-gatling-plugin)?

Comment: It checks for back-end availability?

Comment: and yes it solves my issue :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@george-leung is right, [gradle-plugin](https://github.com/lkishalmi/gradle-gatling-plugin) solved my issue. Thanks :)

Here is the `build.gradle` configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "3.3.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10'
}
```

The simulation file must be in the directory `src/gatling/simulations`.

Then just run the `gradlew gatlingRun` command an it performs the load tests, generating a report in the `build/reports/gatling` directory by default.